# I am trying to reverse the stack using recursion. What is being passed in function fun()? s is an object of class stack

Tags: c++, data-structures

```
//Reverse the stack with fun() and fun1()  
    /*I am unable to understand what is being passed in function fun(). 
I am not sure about the arguement of type stack <int> &s. 
Is it a whole stack being passed or just one node?*/     

void fun1(stack<int> &s, int k)
{
   if ( s.empty())
   {
       s.push(k);
       return;
   }
      int t = s.top(); s.pop();
      fun1(s,k);
      s.push(t);

}

**void fun(stack<int> &s)**
{
    if ( s.empty())
    {
        return;
    }
    int t = s.top(); s.pop();
    fun(s);
    fun1(s,t);
}
```

The program is trying to reverse the stack using the functions fun() and fun1(). My question is only that the arguement stack  &s takes the address of what?

Comment: In C++, the & (in this context) indicates a *reference* to a stack object.  (i.e. when you're passing s into fun(), it's not making a copy of s, rather a reference to the original object is passed in).  This may not be what you want for a recursive function like this.

Comment: So you're a C programmer learning C++ who hasn't met references yet? You probably want to do a bit more study ;-)

Comment: Try and keep your code executable, don't mangle it with emphasis. If you need to draw attention to something use a comment.

Comment: `&expr` and `Type& var` are two separate constructs that happen to use the same token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C++ a **reference** is basically an alias for an existing variable.  They are represented using the ampersand (`&`); `stack<int>&` indicates a reference to a `stack<int>`.  Thus the arguments named `s` in your functions `fun` and `fun1` indicate references to entire stacks, not individual nodes thereof.